# Sweet.js prefix a match in a template

Tags: sweet.js

Given this macro

```
macro type {
  case {_ $attr } => 
  {
   return #{ 
    var a = obj.some$attr
   }
  }
}

type Attr
```

I'm trying to get this output:

```
var a = obj.someAttr;
```

But what I get is

```
var a = obj.some$attr;
```

Adding any non alphanumeric character between `some` and `$attr` correctly outputs the bound value.

Answer (score 0):

Ok just figured out how to do this

```
enter code here

macro type {
  case { $mName $attr } => 
  {
    var wrapperName = makeIdent('some' + unwrapSyntax(#{$attr}), #{$mName});
    letstx $x = [wrapperName];
    return #{ 
       var a = obj.$x
    }
  }
}
```